name of a plastic strip that goes on top of an insect net frame?
It's flexible, and inserts right into the top edge of the window's mosquito net frame.
The window is an aluminum double hung window from 1980s or 90s.
Searched all over, went through "Door & Window Screens" on Home Depot site, can't find it.




That looks like weather stripping.  Might need to take to a big box(home depot) or better a door/window store for a match.  The attachment area is the problem to match.

@crip659 yep that must be it. Thank you!!!
